# Finding the volume of a solid from revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Revolve $y=4+x^2$ bounded by $x=0,$ $x=1,$ and $y=0$ around $x=8$

I have started by splitting the area in two regions and using the shell method to get the part between y=4 and y=5 with:
$$V=2\pi\int_4^5(8-x)(4+x^2)dx$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you want to use the shell method, which is the best choice here, you want to integrate from 0 to 1 (since those are the values for x in your region).  The rest of your setup is fine.

Comment: even though 0 to 4 is a cylinder?

Comment: Yes - if you were using the disc method instead, you could break it up into two pieces and then use the fact that the bottom piece (for $0\le y\le4$) gives a cylindrical shell, to avoid using an integral for that piece.

Comment: Integrate from $0$ to $1$. The answer (mine!) which is leading you astray is that in that example, we were rotating about a line parallel to the $x$-axis (actually, the $x$-axis) and the problem insisted we integrate with respect to $y$. Here we are rotating about a line parallel to the $y$-axis. If they ask you to compute the volume with respect to $y$, you will have to use "washers" and will need to break up the integral.

Comment: So is $V=2\pi\int_0^1(8-x)(4+x^2)dx$ the volume for the entire region?